# How to reshape from long to wide

Tags: stata

I have a single variable in Stata called random_variable containing random numbers, say, from 1 to 100 but may not be sequentially ( maybe 1, 7, 2). I want to create 15 new variables in the data set each one containing the first 7 (7 may be arbitrary, example is for weekdays) entries from random_variable except the 15th one which will contain only 2 entries. (14*7=98 + 2 in last column)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by creating a unique identifier for each observation within each day. Setting up some random data, we have:

```
*create data
clear
set obs 100
gen random_variable = _n

*randomly sort
set seed 12345
gen sortorder = runiform()
sort sortorder
drop sortorder

*create groups using the mod function
gen day = mod(_n-1, 7) + 1
```

The `random_variable` variable is a non-sequential number between 1 and 100, and the `day` variable is the identifier of a day numbered 1 to 7. You could change the number of groups by editing the second argument of the `mod` function. Next, create an `id` variable for each observation within each day.

```
*create a sequential id for each value for each day
sort day
gen id = .
replace id = 1 if day != day[_n-1]
replace id = id[_n-1] + 1 if id == .
```

This sorts the data, identifies the first observation in each day grouping based on the `day` variable, and then creates an id for each observation in the day grouping. Finally, you can reshape the data using the `day` and `id` variables:

```
reshape wide random_variable, i(day) j(id)
```

This yields 16 columns: the 15 columns you requested as well as 1 column to identify the original day that each value was observed.